# Want to redirect series of urls to a new structure with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a bunch of urls like:

```
mydomain.com/category/item1
mydomain.com/category/item2
mydomain.com/category/item3
mydomain.com/category/item4
```

to

```
mydomain.com/new-category/item1
mydomain.com/new-category/item2
mydomain.com/new-category/item3
mydomain.com/new-category/item4
```

using .htaccess!

Anyone can recommend the best way?

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you should try using mod_rewrite for that.

Comment: So everything from "category" goes to "new-category"? Or are there lots of categories that get mapped to new categories?

Answer (score 0):

For each category that gets changed, you'll need a rewrite rule for it. Make sure to add these rules above any existing routing rules that you have in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^category1/(.*)$ /new-category1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category2/(.*)$ /new-category2/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category3/(.*)$ /new-category3/$1 [L,R=301]
```

etc.